# Finding probability for Discrete Binomial distribution problems

Tags: statistics, probability

## Problem Description:

In each of 4 different competitions, Jin has 60% chance of winning. Assuming that the competitions are independent of each other, what is the probability that: Jin will win at least 1 race?

Given Binomial distribution Parameters:
n=4
p=0.60

## Hint:

P(x>=1)=1-P(x=0)

Use the binom.pmf() function of scipy.stats package to calculate the probability.

Below is the python code i have tried. But it is being evaluated as wrong.

```
from scipy import stats

n = 4
p = 0.6
p1 = 1 - p

p2 = stats.binom.pmf(1,4,p1)
print(p1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the hint, all you need to do is to evaluate the PMF of the binomial distribution at x=0 and subtract the result from 1 to obtain the probability of Jin winning at least one competition:

```
from scipy import stats

x=0
n=4
p=0.6

p0 = stats.binom.pmf(x,n,p)
print(1-p0)
```